# Is there something like a "real-action-to-3D" filter?

Tags: rendering, 3d-modeling, filtering, cutscene

I recently watched the cutscenes of [Call of Duty WWII](https://youtu.be/RQz3BATv1tA?t=18m48s) and was very impressed with the graphics, especially the facial expressions and the creases in the clothing. This is, of course, pre-rendered material and not actual ingame footage.
After doing some research I found that they used [real actors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzugB3oT6FI) for the scenes (Josh Duhamel, Jonathan Tucker, ...) and filmed the scenes like it was a real-action movie.

**This got my wondering if there is some kind of "filter", the turns real-action footage into something that looks like it is entirely computer generated?**

So basically instead of going bottom-up and trying to make the 3D model look as realistic as possible, going top-down and alter real-action footage in a way that it looks like a 3D model.

**Is this done?**

**Clarification:** I am not referring to motion capture, at least I think I am not. I am not talking about filming facial expressions and applying the mechanics to 3D models, but rather taking the whole film and just put a filter on it to make it look 3D.

Comment: Sounds like something one could do with neural network style transfer, though I'm not aware of it ever being done to date. Unless this is something that you yourself are trying to do for a game you're in the process of developing, it's likely not on-topic for this developer Q&A site. You could try the Computer Graphics StackExchange (just be sure to check their help section first to check if it's on-topic there)